# How to run my PC and set it up as a NAS Server for my Work Environment?

Tags: networking, hard-drive, router, network-shares, nas

I am in a work environment where out corporate office is off site, and we have no tech guys at work. We have a lot of common files that are being stored on every one's computers separately, then we email it to our manager and he updates the master file.

My question here is, **is it possible to use my current PC that I work on to act as a NAS Server and at the same time run Windows so that I can work on it?**

I've read that software like [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/) is actually an OS. Can I run the NAS software and my OS side by side? And what happens if I shut my PC down? Right now I am sharing one of my partitions as a NAS, but no-one can access it when my computer is logged off or shut down.

Comment: How is this different from [How can I turn my current PC into a NAS device without losing the PC](http://superuser.com/questions/593226/how-can-i-turn-my-current-pc-into-a-nas-device-without-losing-the-pc)?

Comment: His question was more focused on NAS & RAID aspects (I think), Im trying to keep my drive online when Windows kicks me for inactivity over night. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows - which I'm guessing is the case by default, you don't actually need complexity.   Simply create a directory (folder) then "share" it by right clicking on it and clicking "Share" or similar.   Make sure the other computers on the network are in the same workgroup.

From a practical perspective (ie with the level of knowledge hinted at by your question), you would need a dedicated computer to run FreeNAS - its non-trivial to get 2 OS's running side-by-side - more so when you are talking about filesharing.   FreeNAS is designed to turn a computer into a NAS appliance - not run alongside other machines - and it presents the same way as a shared Windows folder.

Comment: You could run the NAS server in a Virtualbox in Bridged mode.

Comment: @NZD - I agree, but what does that buy over just creating an SMB share ?  The flip side is a lot more ram, space, OS complexity, setting up VM's etc.

Comment: Saves you a dedicated computer (although a VM can only run when the host is running), but otherwise you are right. I's just another option for the OP. The VM has the advantage that he can try using a NAS and if it works for them, use a dedicated machine.

Comment: @davidgo: Thanks a lot, I have this set up, but when Windows logs me off due to inactivity the drive stops being shared. I changed the settings on my computer to never sleep or hibernate, to solve this temporarily. Is there another way around this as I don't want to leave my PC running all night?

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks for fine tuning the Question, sorry about earlier, most forums get annoyed by duplicate topics, thats why i tried to add onto the previous question.

Comment: No, you cant have the drive sharing working if the system is not alive (sleep, hybernate,off).  The best you might be able to do under these circumstances - maybe - is to have the people using it "kick" the system by, for example, using Wake-On-Lan packets if your system supports it.   You would be better off going out and buying a NAS It will be cheaper then leaving a PC on 24/7.

Comment: Never used it, but http://www.amazon.com/Akitio-MyCloud-Mini-Silver-Personal/dp/B005XDGJB8/ref=sr_1_12?ie=UTF8&qid=1458339789&sr=8-12&keywords=NAS has one for US$50+Shipping without disk or http://www.amazon.com/Buffalo-LinkStation-2-Drive-Home-LS220D0402/dp/B00JY4QD4A/ref=sr_1_11?ie=UTF8&qid=1458340051&sr=8-11&keywords=NAS+with+drive for a low-end robust solution including disks.

Comment: @davidgo: Thanks a lot for your time. I would buy a NAS, but my company wont cover my costs, hence my pet project. I am going to try to use "Wake-On-LAN packets" if I can manage to set it up. Thanks again.